# Callback, Promise or Await for API Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, woocommerce, callback, es6-promise

I would like to update 4 pieces of data on Woocommerce via the API. I have just been using them as below with no issues but would like to introduce some error checking and perhaps use promises. Should I use a callback, promise or async/await in this instance?

The first adds an order note and the second function sets the order status:

```
// Update Woocommerce Orders
    var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: process.env.WOOAPI_URL, // Your store URL
    consumerKey: process.env.WOOAPI_KEY, // Your consumer key
    consumerSecret: process.env.WOOAPI_SECRET, // Your consumer secret
    wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
    version: 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
    });

    var data = {
    note: 'Order is complete'
    };

    WooCommerce.post('orders/' + orderId + '/notes', data, function (err, data, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
    });

    var status = {
    status: 'completed'
    };

    WooCommerce.post('orders/' + orderId, status, function (err, states, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: That would depend on which browsers you intend to support, whether you'll be transpiling and/or polyfilling missing features. Even then, it's just an opinion. These are just different ways to skin the cat. Personally, I'd go promises with async/await, but that's just my opinion (because I have a dev environment/setup that allows it, despite older/crapper browsers)

Comment: You already are using callbacks. Yes, (if you ask me!) you should use promises. Yes, when having promises you can also use them with `await` instead of `then`. However, it is quite unclear to me what you are doing here - you are not doing anything sequentially.

Comment: The function code is being used in Node.js on AWS Lambda

Comment: Whatever you do, you should improve your indentation so that it's clear what's nested inside what.